# .htaccess removing file extension is conflicting with folders of the same name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm removing file extensions (like .html) from the url with a .htaccess file. The code in the file is working fine, but as soon as there is a folder with the same name as the file without extension, it redirects to the folder instead of redirecting to the file. For example, if I have a `demo.html` file and a `demo` folder in the same directory, as soon as I type in the searchbar of the browser `www.example.com/demo`, it redirects to the folder, instead of the file. If I delete the folder and I type the same thing again, it works perfectly! Any help would be appreciated :)
Here's the code in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by a conflict with mod_dir. When you request a directory without a trailing slash, mod_dir will "fix" the URL and append a trailing slash with a 301 redirect. After which it will attempt to serve a DirectoryIndex document. This takes priority over your internal rewrite.

To resolve this you need to disable this behaviour with `DirectorySlash Off`.

For example:

```
# Ensure that directory listings are disabled
Options -Indexes

# Prevent mod_dir appending a slash to physical directories
DirectorySlash Off

# Redirect to remove the ".html" extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.?]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R=301]

# Rewrite request to append ".html" extension if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
```

Directory listings (mod_autoindex) need to be disabled when you disable `DirectorySlash` because if mod_autoindex is enabled then when you request the directory without a slash, a directory listing will be generated, regardless of whether you have a `DirectoryIndex` document (eg. `index.html`) in that directory that would ordinarily prevent the directory listing being generated.

Also, I've "fixed" your existing rules that remove and append the `.html` extension. The first rule that removes the `.html` extension could have potentially matched an instance of `.html` that appeared in the query string. And the second rule that appends the `.html` extension would have resulted in a rewrite-loop (500 error) if requesting `/demo/<does-not-exist>` - where `demo` is a directory and a file basename (as in your example).

See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to a related question on ServerFault for more information on this potential rewrite-loop:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly, thank you! Just a quick question, why do I have to disable directory listings? I read that they are a possible security threat, is it because of that?

Comment: Yes, when you disable `DirectorySlash` and mod_autoindex is enabled (ie. to generate directory listings) then when you request the directory without a slash, mod_autoindex will generate a directory listing, even though there might be a `DirectoryIndex` document in that directory that would ordinarily prevent the directory listing being generated.

Comment: I've also updated your existing rules, since there were a couple of "vulnerabilites". I've updated my answer with more explanation.